# Can't download Blob from a Trusted Site in IE11

Tags: javascript, blob, internet-explorer-11

A customer using Internet Explorer 11 has issues downloading files from our website.

They have File Downloads *disabled* for the Internet Zone, File Downloads *enabled* for Trusted Sites and our website is added to their Trusted Sites.

The following is a quick and dirty example of what we are doing in a function to download files on the client side (we use file-saver in real life). This works fine with file downloads enabled for the Internet Zone.

```
var content = "Hello world";
var filename = "hello.txt";
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/plain" });
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
```

The error they are getting is

> hello.txt couldn't be downloaded

We tried everything we can think of and pretty much ran out of ideas. Is this scenario supported? Any ideas of what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add blob to the trusted site, it works for me.

i.e. On internet Explorer, go to tools, then internet option, under security tab, click on trusted site, then click on  the sites button and add 'blob' as a trusted site

Comment: I forgot to answer my own question but this is exactly what we ended up doing this after spending quite a bit of time dealing with Microsoft support.
IMHO this is a workaround and not a proper fix but with IE not being activaly developed anymore it is what it is I guess.